# Login page HTTP but goes through to HTTPS. Can ISP see passwords?

Tags: passwords, https, isp

I noticed last night that my webmail providers homepage is HTTP. From there I login and go through to an HTTPS page and the session remains HTTPS from there.

Does this mean that all my login details and passwords can be read by my ISP?

I checked the source code for the login page and there is a section where the login page is identified as HTTPS but I am not at all knowledgable about how to read source codes etc.

So, my basic question is: Would an HTTPS webform suffice in obscuring passwords etc from your ISP?

EDIT: some additional questions:

Would using MAC OSX or iPad OSX decrease chances of hacking?

Would using a VPN negate chances of hacking? I was using VPN...

Is it likely that a hacker would create a fake login page? Would a webmail service be unaware of this? How would me typing a webmail address lead me to a fake site?

Comment: If you submit the data over a secure connection then the data cannot be intercepted.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the HTTPS traffic, including the passwords, is encrypted.  If the HTTP web page redirects you to an HTTPS site where the passwords get authenticated, then the passwords are not at risk...

...ASSUMING (uh oh...) that the HTTP page is redirecting you to the HTTPS site that you think it is.

And, even if the HTTP page redirects you to the HTTPS site that you think it does, today, you may be in ongoing risk that this won't happen the way you think next week.  So maybe you could get your passwords taken then.

See, with HTTPS, here is how it works: Your web browser checks PKI and your local certificate store, and trusts the HTTPS site.  Then the passwords are encrypted, and you're all good.

The problem with an initial HTTP page is the following: your web browser doesn't verify the HTTP web page.  So an attacker ("Man-In-The-Middle attack") could notice your HTTP traffic, and send you a fake login page.  The fake login page might do this: send your posted passwords to a malicious website, instead of the HTTPS site that you think you're using.  That malicious website might capture your passwords, and then redirect you to the HTTPS website, with your passwords posted to the legitimate HTTPS site.  If done very well, this might be very hard for you to detect.

So the HTTP communication does offer an opportunity for you to get attacked easily, and it may be hard for you to notice that.  However, *if* the HTTP communication is not messed with, then when you submit the passwords to the correct HTTPS site, you oughtta be safe from that point on.

This is assuming that the HTTP site provides you with the login form and sends the posted data to the HTTPS site.  If the HTTP site has you post the data to an HTTP address, and then you get redirected to HTTPS, then you probably are quite vulnerable at having your passwords sniffed at this point.

A good website will just bypass all these worries by using HTTPS early on; as soon as the person gets the initial login page, if not earlier.  (Another technique that is starting to get used more frequently, particularly if site security is actually important, redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS as the very first step, thereby minimizing the amount of HTTP communications.)

EDIT: Adding answers to additional questions:

> Would using MAC OSX or iPad OSX decrease chances of hacking?

No.  Not at all.  This isn't even like the "Mac is immune to viruses" theory, which is also not entirely true.  At least that claim had some decent reasoning behind it: most malware (at the time this theory was quoted) was often designed for Microsoft Windows.

No, rather: the attacks you describe have to do with network traffic.  If you're using Mac OSX or iPad IOS, then I expect you'll be using standard protocols like TCP/IP and Ethernet or Wi-Fi.  These are the exact same standard protocols as the TCP/IP and Ethernet and Wi-Fi that get implemented by other platforms like Microsoft Windows and Linux-based operating systems.  So, using these Apple implementations will not help, not even one little teeny tiny bit, at protecting you from network sniffing.

> Would using a VPN negate chances of hacking? I was using VPN...

Yes, that will help.  Maybe insufficiently, but probably would help.

So if you have a computer at home, and use a VPN to send traffic through your ISP to a network at another location (like where you work, or your school, perhaps?), then someone could still sniff the traffic as it goes from that remote location to the desired website.  However, your web traffic (both HTTP and HTTPS) should be rather immune to network sniffing by the ISP as it goes from your house to the other end of the VPN tunnel.  So this does offer some protection.

Of course, all of that is assuming that the VPN technology is implemented safely/correctly.  If there are vulnerabilities, any of these techniques may fail.  For instance, even HTTPS traffic won't save you sufficiently if your browser accepts certificates made by a device in the middle.

> Is it likely that a hacker would create a fake login page?

If this traffic is financial in nature, then hackers have quite a bit of incentive to make such an attack.

Otherwise...  umm...  well, it seems that I've been reading a lot these days that, even for less important/interesting traffic, attackers are frequently scanning network traffic, and are thwarting security mechanisms.  The exact precise answer might depend on how much you believe in theories about corporate/government conspiracies, but such behavior definitely exists.

> Would a webmail service be unaware of this?

Yes, the webmail provider could be unaware of this.

> How would me typing a webmail address lead me to a fake site?

Let's say that webmail address uses HTTP, not over a VPN.  I own a computer that the network traffic goes through.  (Remember, the Internet is designed for traffic to be relayed over different networks.)  I see that your web browser sends an HTTP request to http://my-favorite-paid-site.com.  Before I relay the traffic onto http://my-favorite-paid-site.com (if I even bother to do that), I send information to your web browser.  Your web browser receives data, which it believes comes from the website, but actually came from me.  Your web browser then shows you a website, and claims that this data came from the website.  However, it actually came from me.

Or, instead of attacking the HTTP stream, I could send you different data when you send out the DNS request.  There are various types of attacks, and plenty of tutorials and books and even college courses that cover such concepts in more detail.  Just search for "MITM" (which stands for "Man In The Middle") to see some different ways that type of threat may be implemented.

Comment: Most important part of this whole answer is the very last paragraph. Read: Login page should be HTTPS.